# Can we scribble on UITableviewCell with out interfering the tableview vertical scroll?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I just want to enable free handwriting on a tableview cell with out actually interfering the table view scroll gestures.

Comment: from a user experience point of view, how would that work? how does the user know whats going to happen when the start panning on any part of the screen ?

Comment: You could temporarily disable user interaction on the table. Or maybe set allows selection on the table to be false.